# How can I create my own pdf file with ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: pdf, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET Core MVC project, I want to output some data contained in the page in `PDF` format. I tried a few libraries but for some reason it didn't work. Is there anyone who can help me? If you support with examples or a project that works directly, I would be very pleased.

The last method I tried is with the iText library. This worked but the blank page came.

`.cshtml` with jQuery lib:

```
<button id="btnPdf">Generate PDF</button>    
$('#btnPdf').click(function () {
                window.open('../Home/PrintStudent?param=1');
});
```

Home controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _oHostEnvironment;

    [Obsolete] 
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;

    private string projectRootPath;
    private string outputPath;
    private string storagePath;
    List<string> lstFiles;

    [Obsolete]
    public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment oHostEnvironment, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
        _oHostEnvironment = oHostEnvironment;
        projectRootPath = _env.ContentRootPath;
        outputPath = Path.Combine(projectRootPath, "wwwroot/Uploads/viewer");
        storagePath = Path.Combine(projectRootPath, "wwwroot/Uploads");
    }

    [Route("PrintStudent")]
    public ActionResult PrintStudent(int param)
    {
        List<PdfModel> oStudents = new List<PdfModel>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            PdfModel oStudent = new PdfModel();
            oStudent.Id = i;
            oStudent.Name = "Student" + i;
            oStudent.Address = "Address" + i;
            oStudents.Add(oStudent);
        }

        StudentReport rpt = new StudentReport(_oHostEnvironment);
        return File(rpt.Report(oStudents), "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

**StudentReport.cs**

```
using Helpers.CommonModels;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DenizAnalizMain.Reports
{
    public class StudentReport
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _oHostEnvironment;

        public StudentReport(IWebHostEnvironment oHostEnvironment)
        {
            _oHostEnvironment = oHostEnvironment;
        }

        int _maxColumn = 3;
        Document _document;
        Font _fontStyle;
        PdfPCell _pdfCell;
        PdfPTable _pdfTable = new PdfPTable(3);
        MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        List<PdfModel> _oStudents = new List<PdfModel>();

        public byte[] Report(List<PdfModel> oStudents)
        {
            _oStudents = oStudents;

            _document = new Document();
            _document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
            _document.SetMargins(5f, 5f, 20f, 5f);

            _pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
            _pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

            _fontStyle = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 8f, 1);
            PdfWriter docWrite = PdfWriter.GetInstance(_document, _memoryStream);

            _document.Open();

            float[] sizes = new float[_maxColumn];

            for (int i = 0; i < _maxColumn; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0) sizes[i] = 20;
                else sizes[i] = 100;
            }

            _pdfTable.SetWidths(sizes);

            this.ReportHeader();
            this.EmptyRow(2);
            this.ReportBody();

            _pdfTable.HeaderRows = 2;
            _document.Add(_pdfTable);

            _document.Close();

            return _memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        private void ReportHeader()
        {
            _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(this.AddLogo());
            _pdfCell.Colspan = 1;
            _pdfCell.Border = 0;
            _pdfTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);

            _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(this.SetPageTitle());
            _pdfCell.Colspan = _maxColumn -1;
            _pdfCell.Border = 0;
            _pdfTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);

            _pdfTable.CompleteRow();
        }

        private PdfPTable AddLogo()
        {
            int maxColumn = 1;
            PdfPTable pdfPTable = new PdfPTable(maxColumn);

            string path = _oHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "/images";

            string imgCombine = Path.Combine(path, "denizyatirimTransparent.png");
            Image img = Image.GetInstance(imgCombine);

            _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(img);
            _pdfCell.Colspan = maxColumn;
            _pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            _pdfCell.Border = 0;
            _pdfCell.ExtraParagraphSpace = 0;
            pdfPTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);

            pdfPTable.CompleteRow();

            return pdfPTable;
        }

        private PdfPTable SetPageTitle()
        {
            int maxColumn = 3;
            PdfPTable pdfPTable = new PdfPTable(maxColumn);

            _fontStyle = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 18f, 1);
            _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Student Information", _fontStyle));
            _pdfCell.Colspan = maxColumn;
            _pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            _pdfCell.Border = 0;
            _pdfCell.ExtraParagraphSpace = 0;
            pdfPTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);
            pdfPTable.CompleteRow();

            _fontStyle = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 14f, 1);
            _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("School Name", _fontStyle));
            _pdfCell.Colspan = maxColumn;
            _pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            _pdfCell.Border = 0;
            _pdfCell.ExtraParagraphSpace = 0;
            pdfPTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);
            pdfPTable.CompleteRow();

            return pdfPTable;
        }

        private void EmptyRow(int nCount)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < nCount; i++)
            {
                _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", _fontStyle));
                _pdfCell.Colspan = _maxColumn; 
                _pdfCell.Border = 0;
                _pdfCell.ExtraParagraphSpace = 10;
                _pdfTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);
                _pdfTable.CompleteRow();
            }
        }

        private void ReportBody()
        {
            var fontStyleBold = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 9f, 1);
            _fontStyle = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", 9f, 0);

            #region Detail Table Header
            _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Id", fontStyleBold));
            _pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            _pdfCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            _pdfCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.Gray;
            _pdfTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);

            _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name", fontStyleBold));
            _pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            _pdfCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            _pdfCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.Gray;
            _pdfTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);

            _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address", fontStyleBold));
            _pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            _pdfCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            _pdfCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.Gray;
            _pdfTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);

            _pdfTable.CompleteRow();
            #endregion

            #region Detail table body
            foreach (var oStudent in _oStudents)
            {
                _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(oStudent.Id.ToString(), fontStyleBold));
                _pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                _pdfCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                _pdfCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.Gray;
                _pdfTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);

                _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(oStudent.Name.ToString(), fontStyleBold));
                _pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                _pdfCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                _pdfCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.Gray;
                _pdfTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);

                _pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(oStudent.Address.ToString(), fontStyleBold));
                _pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                _pdfCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                _pdfCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.Gray;
                _pdfTable.AddCell(_pdfCell);

                _pdfTable.CompleteRow();
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a library. What did you try, what didn't work?

Comment: iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core // DinkToPDF // Select.HtmlToPdf 
I tried these.

Comment: And, what was the problem? If all failed, the problem is most likely the code. iTextSharp has 10M downloads. It wouldn't have even 100 if it didn't work. What did you actually try? Did you get errors? What were those?

Comment: I have not received any errors. In some, I was able to print text, but I could not draw a picture, in others, pdf was opened but it was opened blank. Codes will be very long and complicated. So if there is a solution that you use and make sure, I need you to say at least use this library for guidance.

Comment: In addition, I tried using the 'syncfusion' library, but I could not draw a picture on it.

Comment: You can't expect people to tell you what's wrong with your code without showing that code. Especially when the code is very long and complicated

Comment: I edited the post. You can review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran it using **Rotativa.AspNetCore**. It has a simple usage. For your information.
You can download and use it via nuget.